# TableViewCell not updating properly swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app I created two custom tableview cells.

Problem I am facing now the second tableview cell update with last element of the array only.

In `cellForRowAtIndexpath` array elements are displaying fine.

Consider `[ "Value1", "Value2"  ]` is my array. In tableView only value2 is displaying in two cells.

```
var title = ["value1","value2"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let row = indexPath.row

        let x = Id[indexPath.row]

        if x == 0{

        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell1

            return cell1
        }
        else{

      let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell2

            for index in 0..<myArray.count{
        cell2.titleButton.setTitle(title[index],forState:UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            return cell2
        }
    }
```

I am stuck here, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using the same name for a variable **and** a class is pretty confusing. That's what the naming convention (variable names start with a lowercase and class names with a uppercase letter) is for.

Comment: Just for example i modified that. Actually i am using different class and different variable. And the class name starts with Upper Case Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the solution, reason it was going out of range was because value incremented when cell were dequed as cellforrowAtIndexPath was called every time we scrolled down(since some cells were not visible and these cells were dequed when we scrolled down):-

```
    var name = ["HouseBolo","HouseBolo1","HouseBolo2","HouseBolo3"]
    var propertyVal:Int = 0
    var projectVal:Int = 0
    var type = ["Apartment","Villa","Home","Flat","Plot"]
    var arrangedData = [String]()
    var flatId = [0,1,2,0,0]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I want the Expected Output in Tableview Cell is
        // 1. Apartment 2. HouseBolo 3. HouseBolo1 4. Villa 5. Home


        for item in flatId {
            if item == 0 {
                arrangedData.append(type[propertyVal])
                propertyVal+=1
            }
            else {
                arrangedData.append(name[projectVal])
                projectVal+=1
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrangedData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let flatDetails = flatId[indexPath.row]

        // For Property Cell
        if flatDetails == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PropertyCell

            if(cell != nil) {
                cell!.pType.text = arrangedData[indexPath.row]
            }
           return cell!
        }
        // For Project Cell
        else {

            let cellan = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ProjectCell

            if(cellan != nil)  {
             cellan!.projectName.setTitle(arrangedData[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            return cellan!
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Let me test once. I got new knowledge from you. I appreciate that.

Comment: Of course, only after it works for you. Thank you , its my pleasure to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! searchCell`

in :

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}`

block.

`searchCell` : is a class of type : `UITableViewCell`

After that, go in Storyboard and change the identifier of your cell with : "cell"

Comment: I have done all this stuff. I am able to get data in each different Cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
}
```

You have to add **your custom tableview cell class name** in the place of **UITableViewCell**

Something like this -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  **custom tableview cell class name**
{
}
```

And also in Storyboard ,change the identifier of your cell with : "cell1" and "cell2"

Comment: So how can i return multiple tableviewcells at at time. According to your concept only one cell can be returned.

Comment: You are already using if..else by this you can get specific cell.

Comment: Yeah. I am getting specific cell. That's not a problem. Data is also displaying in the cells. If i print(title[0]) in my code, i will get output "value1". And print(title[1]) will populate output "Value2". This is not updating in tableviewcells.

Answer (score 0):

In the code...

```
let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell2

for index in 0..<myArray.count{
  cell2.titleButton.setTitle(title[index],forState:UIControlState.Normal)
}
return cell2
```

you are iterating over 'myArray' and assigning the value to 'cell2.titleButton'.  Cell 2 will always have the last value assigned to it's title. It's assigning it to 'value1', then reassigning it to 'value2'.  Looping through the array seems to be the issue (assuming the cells are displaying - just always showing the title from the last item in the array.